# I need the counts of lines between two matching patterns

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have my input like below -

```
[11/Jul/2016:13:40:43 +0000] "POST --" 200 - 7
[11/Jul/2016:13:40:43 +0000] "POST --" 200 - 7
[11/Jul/2016:13:40:47 +0000] "POST --" 200 - 7
[11/Jul/2016:13:40:47 +0000] "POST --" 500 - 7
[11/Jul/2016:13:41:48 +0000] "POST --" 200 - 7
[11/Jul/2016:13:41:49 +0000] "POST --" 500 - 7
[11/Jul/2016:13:42:12 +0000] "POST --" 500 - 7
```

I want the number of lines between the input 13:40 to 13:41 , in this case a count as 6.

I tried below options

```
echo sed -n '/^START_TIME/,/^END_TIME/ p' somelogfile.log | wc -l

echo sed -n '/^13:40:43$/,/^13:41:43$/ p' somelogfile.log | wc -l
```

but I get 1 all the time.

Can someone check and let me know what is going wrong here ?

Comment: The i/p lines got truncated . So in this case o/p should be 3.

Comment: Is the ending timestamp (`13:41:43`) not present in the line on purpose, i.e. do you need a numerical comparison for the timestamps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `echo` is going to generate only one line and `wc` is counting this line.

Note that the ending timestamp does not exist `13:41:43`, and the anchors used (`^` and `$`) are too restrictive.

Remove the `echo` and try this:

```
sed -n '/13:40:43/,/13:41:49/p' somelogfile.log | wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. This is working perfect.

Comment: This is my first post here and I am not very sure how it works. But I am unable accept your post as an answer. But this works.

Comment: Then explain the reasons why you could not accept it?

Comment: @user179309, I think you tried to accept more than one answer. You can vote up all you feel useful, but only accept one. Take a peek at [the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the help pages.

Answer (score 1):

If the chronological order is the same as the lexical order you can just do:

```
awk '$0>="[11/Jul/2016:13:40:00" && $0<="[11/Jul/2016:13:41:59"' file | wc -l
```

This checks if the value is greater or equal to the first date and less or equal to the second date. If in `awk` no command is given, `awk` just prints the line.

Comment: As long as the start and end dates are on the same day, that should work. (Probably the best that can be easily done with that horrible timestamp format...)

Answer (score 1):

Let's review this command:

```
echo sed -n '/^13:40:43$/,/^13:41:43$/ p' somelogfile.log | wc -l
```

- Consider what the `echo` does and what goes through the pipe to `wc` (just try without `wc`). That explains why you always get a `1`.
- The regexes you've written are locked to the beginning `^` and end `$` of the line, but of course those timestamps are not the only thing in the line so you should remove the anchors.
- The end condition looks for a timestamp that is not present in your sample, so the match range will never end, printing everything starting at the first match.

Something like this might do approximately what you ask for (outputting `3` with the input file currently shown on the question)

```
sed -ne '/13:40:47/,/13:41:48/p' somelogfile.log | wc -l
```

Comment: Works perfect . Thank you very much for the explanation.