# sed count lines between pattern - multiple files

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, pipe, wc

I have multiple `.txt` files in one directory. Each file has a section:

```
DONE
item 1
item 2
item 3
DONE
```

I would like to count the number of lines between the two `DONE` markers for each file seperately.

I used [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295332/i-need-the-counts-of-lines-between-two-matching-patterns) to create this:

```
sed -n "/DONE/,/DONE/ p" *.txt | wc -l > ~/word_count.txt
```

But this combines the counts for each file into one number. Instead I would like output like this:

```
file1.txt 3
file2.txt 5
file3.txt 6
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate that process and amend `word_count.txt` each time? Or would I have to do it for each file manually by replacing `*.txt`

Comment: Dude, you just loop over the file names and _append_ the result to `word_count.txt` e.g. `for f in ./*.txt; do { printf '%s ' "$f"; sed -n '/DONE/,/DONE/p' "$f" | wc -l; } >>~/word_count.txt; done` - sure the `awk` solution below is better (more efficient, faster) so should be preferred over any kind of loop.

Comment: I like this method, want to put it as an answer?

Comment: Play with it and once you figure out how it works explain that in an answer and you'll get at least one upvote ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `awk` to *count*.

```
awk '
  FNR == 1 {inside = 0}
  $0 == "DONE" {
    if (inside) print FILENAME, n
    n = 0
    inside = ! inside
    next
  }
  inside {n++}' ./*.txt
```

That will print a record for each `DONE...DONE` section in each file, which means nothing will be printed if there's no such section. To print `0` for those, you'd need the GNU implementation of `awk` with its `BEGINFILE`, `ENDFILE` special statements:

```
awk '
  BEGINFILE {DONE_count = 0}
  $0 == "DONE" {
    if (++DONE_count % 2 == 0) print FILENAME, n
    n = 0
    next
  }
  DONE_count % 2 {n++}
  ENDFILE {if (!DONE_count) print FILENAME, 0}' ./*.txt
```

Or run one `awk` per file:

```
for file in ./*.txt; do
  awk '
    $0 == "DONE" {
      if (++DONE_count % 2 == 0) print FILENAME, n
      n = 0
      next
    }
    DONE_count % 2 {n++}
    END {if (!DONE_count) print FILENAME, 0}' "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '
   eof and !$a && print "$ARGV: ", 0+$a;          # no DONEs => ans=0
   next unless /DONE/ && !$a ... /DONE/;          # skip non-DONE ranges
   /DONE/ and !$a++ && next;                      # begin DONE range
   !/DONE/ and !eof and $a++,next;                # middle of DONE range
   !/DONE/ and eof and $a=2;                      # lone DONE => ans=0
   print "$ARGV: ", ($a-2, $a=0, close ARGV)[0];  # end of DONE range
                                                  # at the end we do 4 things: 1) subtract 2 from sum, 2) print filename+sum, 3) reset sum, and 4) skip the current file and jump to the next file in queue.
' ./*.txt
```

With `sed` we can do this on a per-file basis:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
   printf '%s: %d\n' "$f" "$(sed -e '/DONE/,/DONE/!d; //d' "$f" | wc -l)"
done
```

The difference will be in the scenario when we shall not be having a closing DONE.